# org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellCheckException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang=en&hl=en

Tags: java, spell-checking, spelling

I'm using google-speller-api.jar it throws  exception

```
org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellCheckException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang=en&hl=en
```

Here is my code

```
SpellChecker spellChecker=new SpellChecker();
spellChecker.setLanguage(Language.ENGLISH);


SpellRequest spellRequest=new SpellRequest();
spellChecker.setOverHttps(true);
spellRequest.setText("aple");

SpellResponse spellResponse=spellChecker.check(spellRequest);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google discontinued this service thats why you are getting 404 error since that service is not available.

Check this [issue report](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-spelling-java/issues/10)

Comment: thank you. Are there another services like google-speller.jar?

Comment: @DoctorDo I'm not aware of any service. Please post a question in http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/